# how can I show page numbers of a pdf in Okular

Tags: pdf, okular

I know epubs do not do page numbering,but pdfs should.
all I have to go by in Okular for progress in a book is the position of the scroll bar.
Is there any way to show the total pages and the current page of a pdf in Okular, preferably whilst reading.

Answer (score 0):

easy,
ctrl+m if you do not have a menu
then
settings, 'show page bar'  (not side bar)
a bar at the bottom has the page number.

Comment: I could also set a shortcut key for it in settings , shortcuts, search for 'bar'

Comment: also showing this bar at the bottom has largely solved another problem, in continuous mode, a page down would 1/3 of the time not show the top line properly, necessitating having to go one line up with the arrow up key. that is now a 1/10 issue if that.